# Use a CPT as a taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

I normally do the same kind of page where I create several CPT (i.e. team, projects, news) and then create separate templates pages where you can see on the team page the projects associate, the news, etc...

I can´t find any other to do that create a taxonomy called "project taxonomy" so the project is tagged with that taxonomy and so the person who is in charge, the news related and so on...
I´m not an expert developer so I use elementor to help myself doing these templates and dynamic.ooo for the post relations.

This would be solved if I could use CPT as taxonomy and generate easy relations. I saw https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/cpt-onomies/ but it´s not updated apparently and no idea when will it be.

Any idea how to do this via functions.php

Note: this is my first post. Thanks for the kindness if you feel i´m a bit lost.

Comment: hello and welcome! I'm struggling to visualise what it is you're trying to build or what the template pages you would normally build are, can you be clearer about what it is you are trying to build from a users perspective so I can mentally map taxonomies and CPT's on to it? Right now everything is phrased in ambiguous technical terms, so I can't picture what it actually looks like

Comment: Hi Tom and thanks for the answer, I´m going to be as clear as possible.
I have a website where you publish Projects, People, News and Cities. The four of them are CPT and they have their description.
I create templates pages (via Elementor) i.e. Projects:
- Description
- People involved in that project.
- News related to that project.
- Cities where that project is developed.
For example > https://www.procc.org/desarrollos/centro-marie-langer-sede-estepa/

I would like to achieve this making my CPT to be taxonomies recognized by wordpress.
Hope is more clear.Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure based on your description as it mentions a lot of technical oriented terms, not user oriented (CPT's Elementor Taxonomy are all technical, what we need to do here is business/data structure oriented, this information), but I suspect the page you linked to doesn't make sense as a taxonomy term, taxonomies and terms for for categorising things, grouping them, filtering them. They aren't meant to be pieces of content themselves. that doesn't mean you can't create a term in a taxonomy for each post

Comment: Is that URL linking to a piece of content, or an archive/listing of content? I see text and contact details, etc. Is your actual problem that you can't use Elementor to layout a taxonomy archive? So you're trying to turn it into a CPT so you can use the layout editor? Have you tried just creating the taxonomies and tagging the various CPT?

Comment: That URL goes to a template page on Elementor for a CPT called Desarrollos. To show the Noticias, Eventos and Equipo (all of them CPT) I had to create the Taxonomy called (as well) Desarrollos so I can relate on the template the different posts.
So I have the CPT Desarrollos but also the taxonomy Desarrollos so afterwards I can create the dynamic template relating all of them.

Comment: Ah, that's very different from a taxonomy archive. which you will have if you've said you want them, but taxonomy archives list posts in a term, they don't have post content, and what you're trying to do would involve multiple follow up queries anyway as you're showing different posts in different sections. Either way there's no such thing as a CPT-taxonomy combined "thing" as you're wanting. My personal recommendation is that you stick with what you're currently doing, or, use the taxonomy archive and sacrifice Elementor/Post content, and build it in code